# Re-assign variables from model in $(document).ready after ajax update

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This might be a simple problem that I have been over thinking, but I can't think of what needs to be done.

```
<div class="commentsMain">
      ... Contents loaded with ajax ...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxPage = @Model.NumberOfPages;
    var nextPage = @Model.CurrentPage + 1;

    // Loads new comments and adds them to the comments main div
    $("#loadNextComments").live("click",function() {
        if (nextPage <= maxPage) {
            $("#loadNextCommentsDiv").remove();
            loadNewComments('@Url.Action("Comments", "Comments")', nextPage, @Model.CommentItemId, @Model.CommentItemType );
            nextPage++;
        }
    });
     // This function submits the comment and then the nextPage variable
     // is supposed to be set back to @Model.CurrentPage + 1
     $('#commentSubmitButton').on("click",submitComment(@Model.CommentItemId, @Model.CommentItemType, addAction, nextPage));
});
</script>
```

After the commentSubmitButton click I need the nextPage variable to be re-assigned with the proper value from the model. How can I achieve this? I could do this in the ajax "success" function, but the function is in an external file and I don't know if I can somehow re-assign the variable from there.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `var`-keyword before `nextPage` and `maxPage` to make the variables global

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea about that.